# How can i package mysql db into my installer like(install4j)

Tags: mysql, installation, packaging

i am working on developing accounting program and i am using mysql DB,
and i use install4j for making windows installer,
i can package jre in my installer,
but my question is how can i package mysql DB in this installer,

thanks.

Comment: Why do you use MySQL? This requires a running mysql server on every machine in order to use your software. You should use SQLITE instead!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Installer of MySQL into yout File-Set.

During the installation of your app (After the "Install Files"-Action), you can start the MySQL-Installer with an "Run Executable or Batchfile"-Action.

Your Installation-Directory woul look like this:

> ~\myApp\program.exe
>
> ~\myApp\InstallationFiles\setup-mysql.exe